# Update column in Django with child columns

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-annotate

I have 2 models `Parent`, `Child`

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    id = Base64UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    cost = models.DateTimeField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)

class Child(models.Model):
    id = Base64UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    cost = models.DateTimeField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name= "children", related_query_name= "child")
```

I need to populate `cost` column of `Parent` objects to maximum cost of all children of that parent

I have tried to annotate to a new column `new_cost`, and its works.

```
parents.annotate(new_cost=Max('child__cost'))
```

But I need to populate values to existing column `cost`. Tried something like this, but not working.

```
parents.update(cost=Max('child__cost'))
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you should have  a `cost` field in the `Parent`, normally it is better to just annotate it when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Probably that can be achieved with a [`Subquery` expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

Parent.objects.update(
    cost=Subquery(Child.objects.filter(
        parent_id=OuterRef('pk')
    ).values('cost').order_by('-cost')[:1])
)
```

I would however advise to simply use `.annotate(…)` when you need the largest cost of the related `Child`s.

Answer (score 0):

Use `aggregate` againist to `annotate`

```
test = parents.aggregate(new_cost=Max('child__cost'))
parents.update(cost=test["new_cost"])
```

Comment: This will set for *all* `Parent`s the `cost` to the maximum of all children of all `Parent`s, likely the OP want to set this *per* `Parent`.

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'aggregate'. gettig this error

Comment: @PARRE PRITHVI   I think @Willem Van Onsem is right its not a best practice to have ```cost``` for two models.. you can use annotate or have a ```@propety``` cost in parent model

Comment: But if you want do it, show how you get `parents`